# How do I skip certain elements in a list in a python for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a for loop that compares numbers within a list to each other, but I need to exclude certain elements of the list from the comparison. The index value of the elements I need to exclude from the for loop are in a separate list called switch:

`switch = [451, 828, 1214, 1559, 1905, 2197, 2535, 2875, 3237, 3515, 3787, 4119, 4366, 4628, 4873, 5088, 5415, 5737, 6012, 6162, 6504, 6965, 7327, 7571, 7898, 8146, 8473, 8823, 9181, 9466, 9765, 10066, 10239, 10514, 10786, 10921, 11224, 11524, 11784, 12169, 12431, 12702]`

How would I be able to skip these index values in my for loop? Thanks for any help.

For reference, this is part of my for loop:

```
for index, lr in enumerate(choices[:-1]):
if choices[index] == 1:  
    if reward[index] == 1:   
        if choices[index + 1] == 1:  
            win_stay.append(1)
        elif choices[index + 1] == 0:  
            win_stay.append(0)
    elif reward[index] == 0:  
        if choices[index + 1] == 0:  
            lose_switch.append(1)
        elif choices[index + 1] == 1:  
            lose_switch.append(0)
```

...

Comment: maybe to wrap the logic inside the for loop in `if index in swich`

Comment: Inside your loop, BEFORE your first `if`, add a separate `if` that says `if lr in switch: continue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your for-loop is correct, this should work:

```
for index, lr in enumerate(choices[:-1]):
    if index not in switch:
        if choices[index] == 1:  
            if reward[index] == 1:   
                if choices[index + 1] == 1:  
                    win_stay.append(1)
                elif choices[index + 1] == 0:  
                    win_stay.append(0)
            elif reward[index] == 0:  
                if choices[index + 1] == 0:  
                    lose_switch.append(1)
                elif choices[index + 1] == 1:  
                    lose_switch.append(0)
```

The `if index not in switch:` part just makes sure the index isn't in your list `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your current index is in you skiplist.

```
skip = [1,3]
letters = ['a','skip1','b','skip2','c']
correct = []
for index,letter in enumerate(letters):
    if index not in skip:
        correct.append(letter)
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: This completely changes the code format from a for-loop to a list comprehension. It's clear from the OP's example that what the code does is impossible to translate to a list comprehension.

Comment: so I could take it out if you'd like me to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [a continue statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

```
for index, lr in enumerate(choices[:-1]):
  if index in switch:
    continue
  # rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The itertools module has filterfalse that might be useful here:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

leave_out = [2, 3, 4, 5]
filter_it = lambda x: x in leave_out
for i in filterfalse(filter_it, range(10)):
    print(i)

0
1
6
7
8
9
```